# Stack Override: Rank answers by usefulness

Tags: app, chrome-extensions

[image: example page]

## Stack Override

This extension is a part of my final year project for a computer science degree. It displays notifications when the browser loads a Stack Overflow question page. Once clicked, the notification calls a web API I have created and a new tab is opened displaying the answers ranked according to my application.

Take part and give feedback, your opinion of the rankings is welcome.

[image: rate answer rankings]

Feedback will help to improve the quality of the rankings.

[image: thanks]

## Install

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stackoverride/deckmfefillmikcadfmapaokkhbfdblh

## Information

http://stackoverride.no-ip.org/howto

Comment: I would love to try it but I only use Firefox :(

Comment: yes at the moment the extension is only supported in chrome... however the extension is really only a means of transport to the web app if you get me... to use it manualy you could get question ids and place them in this url, stackoverride.no-ip.org/rank/questionidhere ... thats all the extension dose.. feel free do make a quick firefox plugin if you want :) I have never made one before so chose chrome, but would like to support firefox

Comment: I'm afraid you'd need to explain a lot more, to make people install this. Like: how does your rating work and how would it be better than the votes we're already seeing?

Comment: ...doesn't the vote count already do this?

Answer (score 2):

As you're saying the Chrome extension is just opening the webpage, here's a bookmarklet to do the same for those not using Chrome.

```
javascript:
(function(){
  var id = location.href.match(/http:\/\/stackoverflow\.com\/questions\/(\d+)/);
  if(id){
    window.open('http://stackoverride.no-ip.org/rank/' + id[1]);
  }
  else{
    alert('Works for question URLs on stackoverflow.com only.');
  }
}
)()
```

Unfortunately, one cannot add such links here, so it needs [another place to be linked from](http://jsbin.com/uguqix/1/).

(I have not used Stack Override myself.)